# How to populate JSON into table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, html-table

So far I have created a function that when you click on a node, it populates information linked with that node into a table. What I'm struggling to do is append a table row to have each item in the json start on a new line. Currently I am appending paragrapgh tags which spits all the information for that column into a single column (no rows). In my table there are 5 columns and in my code... 'tab1' ect repersents each column. Is it possible to append table rows?

**JS:**

```
d3.json("transactions.JSON", function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);

json.forEach(function(company) {
  nameLookup[company["Company Number"]] = company["Short Name"];
});

var inputdata = d3.select("tab1").selectAll("td")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.lenderCompany == nodeValue && d.type == "loan"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return nameLookup[d.lenderCompany]
  })

var inputdata = d3.select("tab2").selectAll("td")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.lenderCompany == nodeValue && d.type == "loan"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return nameLookup[d.receivingCompany]
  })


var inputdata = d3.select("tab3").selectAll("td")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.lenderCompany == nodeValue && d.type == "loan"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.valueUSD;
  })

var inputdata = d3.select("tab4").selectAll("td")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.lenderCompany == nodeValue && d.type == "loan"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  })

var inputdata = d3.select("tab5").selectAll("td")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.lenderCompany == nodeValue && d.type == "loan"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.interest;
      })
  });
}
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.valueUSD;
          })
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table tableDesign">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Second Company</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th>Employee</th>
                  <th>Bonus</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <tab1 class="tableRow"></tab1>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <tab2 class="tableRow"></tab2>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <tab3 class="tableRow"></tab3>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <tab4 class="tableRow"></tab4>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <tab5 class="tableRow"></tab5>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: what is your goal? Can you use jquery?